# Number of distinct shops

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math

A person is at origin of a number line, which ranges from negative infinity to positive infinity.
Given a string consisting of characters L and R, L means the person goes from x to x-1 and R means, he goes from x to x+1.
Given some queries having range [u,v]. Find how many unique numbers the person visited if the indices from u to v is ignored.

For example
consider 1-based indexing
string - RRRRRR
Queries - [[1,4],[2,4]]
Output - 3, 4
Explanation - [1,4] ignore indices from 1 to 4, string remains RR. Person goes to +1 and +2 and he was already at 0. So total houses = 3

The queries should be answered instantly. I thought of the simple brute force approach but that will be O(Q*N) and 1<= Q,N <= 10^5. I also thought of doing something with prefix sum but didn't get full idea. Can anybody help me to think of an efficient algo? Coding I can do myself

Comment: Given a query `[a,b]`, you need five pieces of information. 1) The maximum excursion to the left for the sequence that ends at `a-1`. 2) The maximum excursion to the right for the sequence that ends at `a-1`. 3) The end point for the sequence that ends at `a-1`. 4) The maximum excursion to the left for the sequence that starts at `b+1`. 5) The maximum excursion to the right for the sequence that starts at `b+1`. All of that information can be computed in O(N) time, and each query can then by processed in O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Preprocessing: In O(n) time, find the leftmost & rightmost position visited, call these 'start' and 'end'.
2. Given a query [a,b], convert it to [a', b'] where a' = max(a, start) and b' = min(b, end).
3. Return (end - start) - (b' - a').

All the work per query is O(1), with O(n) preprocessing.

For example consider 1-based indexing string - RRRRRR Queries - [[1,4],[2,4]]

```
start = 0
end = 6
q1: a=1, b=4. Since these are in-range, a'=1 and b'=4. (6-0) - (4-1) = 6-3 = 3.
q2: a=2, b=4. Same reasoning: (6-0) - (3-1) = 6-2 = 4.
```